# Solving $u_{\epsilon \eta} = \frac{ u_\epsilon - u_\eta}{4 (\epsilon - \eta) } .$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, canonical-transformation

I'm trying to solve the following PDE

$$y^2 u_{xx} - u_{yy} = 0.$$

I've found its canonical form as 
$$u_{\epsilon \eta} = \frac{ u_\epsilon - u_\eta}{4 (\epsilon - \eta) } .$$

However, I'm having trouble in solving this PDE. I've tried solving with mathematica, and that gave me

$$u = \frac{ x + y^3}{ 3} ,$$
but, I need to know how to obtain such a result from the canonical form of the given PDE.

**Edit:**

The coordinate transformations are 
$$\epsilon = x + y^2 / 2 \qquad \eta = x - y^2 /2$$

Comment: what is your coordinate transformation?

Comment: @Dylan Good question! See my edit please.